# d3.js filters not working as expected

Tags: d3.js

When i try to filter the data based on the column selected, the return value is not as expected. I am trying to filter the data based on the application selected through the click of the column in the table.

```
    d3.text(fileRef, function(datasetText) 
            {


        parsedCSVref = d3.csv.parseRows(datasetText);

        var sampleHTMLref = d3.select("#TableContents")
            .append("table")
            .attr("style", "margin-left: 20px")
            .selectAll("tr")
                .filter(function(d){ return d.Application === a.innerHTML})
            .data(parsedCSVref)
            .enter().append("tr")
.selectAll("td")

            .data(function(d){return d;})
            .enter().append("td")
```

Comment: You'll need to give us some more information. What is `a` in your filter function? What does your data look like? What are you trying to achieve with the code?